# How to define a global custom RoutedCommand?

Tags: wpf, routed-commands

I would like to use the same custom RoutedCommand for 2 buttons, which are in separate windows.

In order to not repeat the code, i want to define the command somewhere in the app and bind it to both buttons.

I thought of using Style to achieve that. Below, I reproduce my issue in a simple sample.

I declare the Style in App.Xaml :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="CommandBindings">
        <Setter.Value>
    <!--<Window.CommandBindings>--> <!--I tried with or without this. Doesn't change-->
                <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:App.testBindingCommand}"
                    Executed="OnExecuted" CanExecute="OnCanExecute" />
      <!--</Window.CommandBindings>-->
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
 </Application.Resources>
```

And the custom command in App.Xaml.cs :

```
public static RoutedCommand testBindingCommand = new RoutedCommand();

    private void OnExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OnExecuted");
    }

    private void OnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("OnCanExecute");

        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
```

The compiler does not like the code and give an error :

*error MC3080: The Property Setter 'CommandBindings' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor.*

AFAIK, the Window class has a CommandBindings property.

1) Is the use of Style to declare global CommandBindings correct ? If not, how can i do ?

2) Why the property CommandBindings can't be set by the style ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error message because you are setting the value of the `CommandBindings` property (which is of type `CommandBindingsCollection`) to an instance of `CommandBinding`. Even if the property has a setter (which it doesn't), you can't set a `CommandBinding` to a `CommandBindingsCollection`.

Consider the case of binding a command normally:

```
<Window>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:App.testBindingCommand}"
            Executed="OnExecuted" CanExecute="OnCanExecute" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
</Window>
```

This isn't setting the `CommandBinding` to the `CommandBindings` property, but rather adding it to the `CommandBindings` collection of the `Window`.

Do you have to use a `RoutedCommand`? Maybe it would be better to use a different implementation of `ICommand` - maybe one that calls a `delegate` when the command is executed. [Kent Boogaart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380/kent-boogaart) has an implementation of [DelegateCommand](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html) that could work (there are many other similar implementations floating around, too - or you could write your own).

Comment: Indeed you are right for the binding between CommandBindingsCollection and CommandBinding. That's why i tried <Window.CommandBindings> at first (see the comments in app.xaml)

I will take a lokk at DelegateCommand

Comment: You were right. Using RelayCommand (or DelegateCommand) is much more easier and avoid using CommandBinding. Thanks